# What is this huge succulent plant?

Tags: identification, succulents

I recently saw this plant in a shop. It looks like an amazingly big succulent.

What kind is it? I wonder if it needs much light and if it produces flowers?

[image]
[image]

[image: Succulent or Cacti leaves]

## Edit

Zoom to the area where flowers emerge
(I suspect):

[image: Night Blooming Cereus possible flower bud]

Comment: I don't think its a succulent - it looks similar to one of the ferns to me, although its not exactly right, something like Kangaroo Fern maybe, but there are literally thousands of ferns

Comment: Visually identical to something I have which I would definitely call a succulent - thick, fleshy leaves - but it was an inherited/abandoned plant so I don't know what it is, either. I don't recall it flowering and it's on the whole not difficult to understand its abandonment. These pictures do have a slightly misleading look of fronded leaves, but the "fronds" are just individual leaves like the one in the foreground of the last picture that happen to be aligned that way behind another leaf and stem. I'd go for a massive jade plant 10 times out of 10 over this thing.

Comment: Ok, Ecnerwal, the lower picture does look like a succulent!  Have you seen Ben's answer?  The top one is not the same plant at all...and Bamboo has that as Kangaroo Fern which is what I remember.  Are these the same plant?

Comment: @Bamboo  Am I missing something such as immature leaves or these two pictures show two different plants?

Comment: @stormy - yea, they do look like two different plants to me too,  but only one is mentioned,  so I assume its from a different angle maybe, because we can't see the whole plant at once in any of the pics

Comment: Epiphyllum. For sure. Guys, how do you even consider this a fern? There is nothing remotely fern-like about it. *Surprised*

Comment: Feeling a bit smug are ya?  Grins!!  Whilst looking through the ID stuff, I was surprised myself.  Epiphyllum was part of the family in the second picture.  I really think the confusion was those two pictures are of 2 different plants.  Check out a new question concerning the same plant...

Comment: In the last photo. the sprout from the leaf margin is going to turn into a fuzzy pink flower. I doubt it is a succulent or a fern. You can't give it too much water I have several because I put leaves in my pond.It is exceptionally hardy if warm and wet. I was told it is native to Vietnam and is common there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It reminds me of a Night Blooming Cereus. I've never grown one, so can't comment on their need.  My folks have theirs growing in normal household conditions, getting western light.  They are amazing plants - sending up fragrant blooms that last a single night.  This [page](http://www.worleys.com/bonsai/specific/nbc/) seems to offer a decent overview.

Comment: Well, Ben!  Where have you been?  Sure looks like it but I think Bamboo's Kangaroo Fern is the closest.  Hey aren't you part entomologist?  We've had some super questions needing your expertise if you are.

Comment: Are these two pictures of the same plant?  I think your ID goes well with the second picture, Ben.  Bamboo's goes well with the first or am I the one confused?

Comment: Nope, not much entomology experience.  Public horticulture,  irrigation,  and plants.

Comment: This indeed looks like the one! So it's rather *cacti* than *succulent*... Thanks so much! It will bloom, and how beautifully! I'll add a zoom to the place where I think flowers will come out. I'll try go back to this store and see how they grow.

Answer (score 4):

On first sight i also thought it was sone kind of fern but the zoom shows definitely a cactus. What you were zooming in at is a new leaf , not a blossom.
In my opinion it is species out of genus Epiphyllum.

From your photos it is hard to determine which species exactly so i would suggest to google "epiphyllum" and look for photos.

Edit: maybe epiphyllum oxypetalum, due to the thin, fernlike leaves, but this is mere speculation.

Edit 2: Night-blooming cereus (selenicereus grandiflorus) is definitely wrong. Those have angular stems and nothing that resembles leaves.

Final edit:
I am quite sure now that itis epiphyllum oxipetalum.
I found a video on youtube featuring the plant:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=CXxFdpT7CZA

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it is a "Queen of the Night". They only bloom at night and have an intoxicating fragrance.Occasional watering. One of the most beautiful flowers we have ever raised.

Answer (score 1):

This one of the 'Bird's Nest Ferns'...a very sick one at that.  These plants need an awful lot of humidity, perfect fluffy soil (potting soil), acidic soil, no tap water, water that is pure pure pure.  Very sensitive.  The perfect combination of chemicals (fertilizer), lots and lots of micro/macro organisms. You'll find these in stores sold as house plants. Very few ever make it for long unless its owner understands a fern's needs.

Certainly not a succulent which is a desert plant.  This is a rain forest plant.  You should see how beautiful these are when healthy.  You'd have to go to a production greenhouse dedicated to growing ferns.  They last long enough to make the owner feel as if they've done something wrong.  They either quit purchasing plants and call themselves a black thumb, OR they'll try again buy purchasing even more 'stuff' to baby their plant.

Ferns do not produce flowers nor seed.  They produce spores for reproduction.

Comment: The thing I have that looks just like this has been going strong for 10 or more years despite having been subjected to all sorts of neglect.

Comment: That's not a fern. It's rather some kind of *Cereus* like @Ben pointed.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, you should help this thing of yours thrive and grow its flowers, shouldn't you?

Comment: @Ecnerwal That second, or lower plant is that the one you have?  From what I've seen, looks like something I would baby!

Comment: Not all cactus grow in the desert. There are many species of "Jungle" cactus that grow in Central America. The pictured plant clearly has areoles which would indicate it's a cactus.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a photo and information on Kangaroo Fern ([Microsorum  diversifolium](https://www.houseplant411.com/houseplant/kangaroo-fern-how-to-grow-care) - not entirely sure it is that, but it might be. Obviously, the one in your pictures isn't in great condition. I'm not sure it's exactly the right one, but I can't think of any other that I know that it might be. No flowers, bit of a sprawler and its an epiphytic fern. I don't think it's attractive in any way, but each to his own, we're all different and have different tastes.

Comment: I really don't think so, though I'd go with the unattractive and should probably pitch the refugee I keep watering.

Comment: Nope, that's not the one. Probably my pictures weren't accurate enough.