# Can anyone identify this plant that grows leaves from its leaf?

Tags: identification, leaves

This plant has been growing in my garden (south India) for a while. Would like to know its name so that I can take better care of it. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It looks like a younger version of this plant https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30935/what-is-this-huge-succulent-plant

Comment: Epiphyllum...but thinned because of low light?  What is that tourniquet doing on the lower stem in the picture?

Comment: Alina thanks for that. Looks like it's a Night Blooming Cereus. @stormy that's just to hold the plant upright after repotting.

Comment: I feel better but that needs to come off soon or even better get a little stick with a Y at the end to prop up that branch.  Move the stick up and down every now and then.  You want it to hold itself up and a brace like this will only make that branch weaker.  No biggie.  These plants like to 'fountain' over the sides of pots anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a Night Blooming Cereus (Epiphyllum oxypetalum).

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely some kind of *Cacti* plant.

I would say it's from the [Schlumbergera](https://www.google.fr/search?q=SCHLUMBERGERGERA&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjciZfD3NDSAhWpDMAKHSH-C0YQ7AkIMw) group.

It's quite easy to multiply by just cutting one of the healthy leaves and putting it in light humus in another pot.

Comment: Good info, but now I'm pretty sure it's Night Blooming Cereus. Thanks @Alina for the hint.