# What plant is this ; white /pink flowers grow from leaf margin

Tags: identification, houseplants

What plant is this? It has white /pink flowers growing from the leaf margin. It loves water, and shows an irregular growth habit. I was told it is from Vietnam.

[image]
[image]

Comment: very similar to the one I had here (except it had no flower at the time I spot it) https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30935/what-is-this-huge-succulent-plant

Answer (score 4):

It's an *Epiphyllum*, a Central American genus of cacti. I'm not sure of the species, but *Epiphyllum oxypetalum* is the most common in cultivation.

Answer (score 2):

It may have come from Vietnam, but it's not a native of Vietnam. Cactus are native to the New World only. Any cactus on any other continent is a transplant. SE Asia has been growing several of the "jungle" cactus varieties which have big fruit (dragon fruit).

This group of cactus from Central and South America are definitely NOT cold hardy.

Your specimen is quite nice.

Comment: Thanks :What really confused me was the flower on the leaf margin. I have never seen that before , if I don't count the prickly pear and Christmas cacti on my deck !!!

Comment: Yep, that's where the areoles are, on the edge of the (I guess they're called) stems. Epiphyllium are epiphytic, meaning they aren't dependent on soil to get water and nutrients. They are "jungle" cactus which drape across and through trees/bushes. They can get very long with age. The flowers may be scented. They are also used for hybridizing to create different flower colors.